# 503 error on HTTP request - inner message

Tags: iis, sharepoint-2010

I am sending an HTTP request to the SharePoint server (from SharePoint web page) to read a document on the same server (in SharePoint library). I am getting 503 error and document is not loaded.

How can I catch this error message on IIS to get more information (details or inner message) about this exception? This error is to general, and I think only getting more details about it would be beneficial. Thanks!

Comment: there is a way to catch and log server errors (like 503) directly on IIS, but can't find where it is exactly. it's like filtering such messages or something.

Comment: Fixed. Proxy was the problem. To disable it, I have used "request.Proxy = null;"

Comment: I know its late but if you fixed it, it would be great if you added what fixed it for you as an answer and accepted that, it would help for anybody who might encounter this issue in the future :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the code that fixed this issue:

```
var uri = "mysite.com";
var request = WebRequest.Create(uri);
request.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
request.PreAuthenticate = true;
request.Proxy = null;
HttpWebResponse webResponse = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
```

Proxy must be set to null

Answer (score 0):

do a

```
try{ 
//try to read
} 
catch(Exception er)
{
 lblError.Text = "Details:"+er.Message;
}
```

Comment: already tried it. inner exception is empty. only 503 is there with no additional details.